# How does Asp.net Knows which Page to Generate?

Tags: asp.net, html

When a client is on page A.aspx , and he press some button there is a postback.

The server knows which page to rebuild according to the request.

but how does the client knows which page to re-ask ? by the current url of his browser ?

where this information is saved in the client side ?

Comment: Are you referring to an actual button being clicked, or a hyperlink made to look like a button?

Comment: the client usually sends back to the current URL and then the server knows what to do - you decide in the Click event handler of the button what happens and what is sent as an answer to the client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its defined in the `action` property of `<form>`. The client does not need to re-ask, the server sends a response of his request.

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET is just a part of the .NET framework, but what every client sees on a web browser in plain old HTML.

[ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/) gives you several controls that makes it easy to use them programatically, so we can set all sort of things in our code (that is run before the page is showing) to do the exactly what we want.

every link, button, image, grid, it's just HTML tags, like `<a>` for links, `<input type="button">` for buttons etc...

Keep in mind that now, there are 2 variantes of the ASP.NET, the [WebForms](http://www.asp.net/web-forms) and the [MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc) (you can also read about [choosing one in prole of the other](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX09/T23F))

in every **ASP.NET WebForms** there is always a `<form>` on the start of the `<body>` and wrapps all your code, so, any submit will do a PostBack into the same file name, in your example `A.apsx` will always post into `A.aspx`, then if you want, for example, send that request to `B.aspx` you need to have a `Click Event` that would use the `Server.Transfer("B.aspx")` and that would redirect the entire post to `B.aspx` just like it was a post from `B.aspx`

in the newest pattern, the **ASP.NET MVC**, it drives with [Routes](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-custom-routes-cs) witch let's you set up any, every, one, multiple, ways to reach the same page. In MVC the URL does not point to a specific page, but to a specific Controller and it's up to the Controller to send, after processing the data, to a specific View, that is why in MVC there are no pages in the url (though you can add it to the route if you want, and you can accomplish the same with WebForms using a Routing plugin).

**Now**, in MVC it's there is no `<form>` wrapping up your entire code, you need to, if you want to submit something, create your own `<form>` and point to the correct `route`

but, just like in Webforms or any HTML page, posts are made through [form submittion](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp), and it's "path" it's always whats in the form attribute `action` that let's you know what's the next step.

I hope this helps you realizing that there is no big monster in ASP.NET, that is only a way to reuse controls and access them programmatically and that, in the end, it's all HTML :)

Answer (score 1):

A general answer: on the client side it's either a submit from within a form or a link.

The form points to either a relative URL (that means the current URL plays a key role) or an absolute URL (the current URL plays little to no role).

For links it's generally the same: either they are relative or absolute. One big difference: links are use HTTP GET while forms can use HTTP POST (thus transferring more data without encoding them to the URL as parameters).

For a button it's the form that gets submitted.